# What's the opposite of "out loud"?

Tags: phrase-request

What's the opposite of "out loud"? I mean, "out loud" as in "singing out loud", what's the opposite of that? Like instead of singing for real, you do it in your head? What's the best way to say it? I am trying to find a better way to say "Sing inside your head".

Comment: What do you mean by a "better way"? Better and worse are a matter of context!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say "sing to yourself".

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'm reluctant to upvote until you add more detail, even something as simple as an example sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If your lips move while you're reading a book, this is sometimes described as *reading silently*. The same expression could be used for singing:

> Singing *out loud*.
>   → Singing *silently*.

This wouldn't necessarily mean your lips are moving (although I've seen this happen, along with arm gestures to keep time to the imagined music), but that you are mentally listening to the words and notes even though you aren't physically vocalizing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following as they are antonyms of out loud: inaudibly, silently, soundlessly, voicelessly.

- "She was singing inaudibly."
- "I am singing  silently."
- "The mimes were singing soundlessly."
- "Tom had a sore throat and was forced to stand in the choir singing
  voicelessly."

And these are near antonyms of out loud: faintly, feebly, low, noiselessly, quietly, softly.  They aren't truly opposite of out loud.

Hope this helps

Comment: Of your four options, "silently" is common and natural.  The others are uncommon and unnatural.  Perhaps they make sense in context, but it would be helpful to point out the one that requires the least external explanation.

Comment: Silently is the easiest, I guess easy is good? using a child's vocabulary isn't always necessary but is easy. You didn't read my other answer in context. But sure I will try and add more context to those sentences even though they are true antonyms...

Comment: I believe I understand your answer completely.  I just don't agree with it, as written.